# Easiest way to add custom properties to existing controls in winform?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a grid of Panel Controls in Winform. 
I would like for those panels to contain a custom string and custom int property.

What would be the easiest way to achieve that?
One way would probably be extending the Panel control, but I do not want to do big changes to the control, just to add 2 custom properties.

I am using .NET 4.0

Any pointers you can give to me will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are properties of the class, then deriving from Panel and creating a custom implementation are the best bet, especially if you are using this on multiple forms or multiple projects. You could "cheat" by adding extension methods, but setting up individual getter and setter methods to implement properties is a bit more pain than you have to go through.

Comment: What about Tag property?Can I just use that?

Comment: Sure, but it depends on what the data is whether or not this is a good idea. It also depends on whether you intend to reuse it. Supposing no reuse and the data really applies to the control, and you are not "cheating" to get around coding, then the Tag property might be an option. You will combine the string and int into an object.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question:

> One way would probably be extending the Panel control...

Just add your properties and start using the control.

Comment: What about Tag property?Can I just use that?

Comment: @user850010 You could, it just wouldn't be as clean.